# Fill 4 input with one textarea

Tags: jquery

I have a question for the community.

My problem is that I have 4 input files with a maxlength of 60 caracters for a total of 240 caracters.

Because the "backend" of the customer's system, it need to be 4 differents inputs max to be inserted and they say it is not user-friendly to fill 4 fields.

**My solution**

I want to make a textarea and when you fill it, il complete the 4 fields.

```
[input text #1] max60
[input text #2] max60
[input text #3] max60
[input text #4] max60

[textarea max 240]
```

What I am trying to do is to make by javascript/jQuery to fill up the four field while typing in.

At the moment, here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
            // My text area
    $("#inf_notes").bind('keydown', function () {

                    var maxLength = 240;

        if ($(this).val().length <= 60) {
                       // The first 60 caracters
            $('#inf_notes_1').val($(this).val());
        }

        if ($(this).val().length > 60 && $(this).val().length <= 120) {
                      // If more then 60, fill the second field
            $('#inf_notes_2').val($(this).val());
        }

                    // If 121 - 180 ...
                    // If 181 - 240 ...

                    if($(this).val().length == 240) {
                           $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, maxLength));
               $('.alert_textarea').show(); // Simple alert
        else
        {
            $('.alert_textarea').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

It actually works for the first one, but I would like to have some feedbacks to help me complete the script to fill the 3 nexts.

Any guess to complete it?

--
EDIT #1

I found a way that could maybe work!
When the first input is completly filled, it will jump to the next field with a .focus()

```
   $(".inf_notes").bind('keydown', function () 
{
    var notes1 = $('#inf_notes_1').val();
    var notes2 = $('#inf_notes_2').val();
    var notes3 = $('#inf_notes_3').val();
    if (notes1.length == 60) 
    {
        $('#inf_notes_2').focus();
    }
    if (notes2.length == 60) 
    {
        $('#inf_notes_3').focus();
    }
    if (notes3.length == 60) 
    {
        $('#inf_notes_4').focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not just have a single textarea that takes up to 240 characters and then when submitted/needed it splits the content into 4 submit params (or hidden fields if needed)? Also.. if this breaks words up is this ok?

Comment: Because the first developper made a custom post into an array and I need to fill it into a TXT file.. I had the same idea but when I entered into the code, I said to myself that it would be easier to work on the frontend.

Comment: still seems simpler and more reliable to split one value into four at server to fill your array

Comment: I'm better at "frontend" developpment and you do not want to see the backend ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

HTML:

```
<input id="inf_notes_0" type="text" />
<input id="inf_notes_1" type="text" />
<input id="inf_notes_2" type="text" />
<input id="inf_notes_3" type="text" />

<textarea id="inf_notes"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
   $("#inf_notes").keypress(function(){
      var str = $(this).val();
      var chunks = str.replace(/.{60}/g, "$&%_%").split("%_%");
      $.each(chunks,function(i,o){
         $('#inf_notes_'+i).val(o);
      });
   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aDkDM/1/

PS. Note that `keydown` won't affect last typed character, that is why I used `keypress`.

Comment: This solution seems to be working like a charm! I have found a quick solution but it keeps the 4 input fields that I wanted to delete.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Flash Thunder is very beautiful,

1. but in case where a user type **%_%** string anywhere in textarea, the answer may have trouble to handle.
2. The last typed character is not taken into account.

I've worked out a solution that is more primary, that is abandoned. But after reflection, and tested in Google Chrome, I give it here:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
  // My text area
  $("#inf_notes").bind('keyup', function () {
    var maxLength = 240;
    var strInput = $(this).val();
    var lng = strInput.length;

    if (lng <= 60) {
      // The first 60 caracters
      $('#inf_notes_1').val(strInput);
      $('#inf_notes_2').val("");
      $('#inf_notes_3').val("");
      $('#inf_notes_4').val("");
    }
    else if (lng > 60 && lng <= 120) {
      // If more then 60, fill the second field
      $('#inf_notes_1').val(strInput.substring(0, 60));
      $('#inf_notes_2').val(strInput.substring(60, lng));
      $('#inf_notes_3').val("");
      $('#inf_notes_4').val("");
    }
    else if (lng > 120 && lng <= 180) {
      // If more then 120, fill the third field
      $('#inf_notes_1').val(strInput.substring(0, 60));
      $('#inf_notes_2').val(strInput.substring(60, 120));
      $('#inf_notes_3').val(strInput.substring(120, lng));
      $('#inf_notes_4').val("");
    }
    else if (lng > 180 && lng <= 240) {
      // If more then 180, fill the fourth field
      $('#inf_notes_1').val(strInput.substring(0, 60));
      $('#inf_notes_2').val(strInput.substring(60, 120));
      $('#inf_notes_3').val(strInput.substring(120, 180));
      $('#inf_notes_4').val(strInput.substring(180, lng));
    }

    if(lng > maxLength) {
      $('#inf_notes_1').val(strInput.substring(0, 60));
      $('#inf_notes_2').val(strInput.substring(60, 120));
      $('#inf_notes_3').val(strInput.substring(120, 180));
      $('#inf_notes_4').val(strInput.substring(180, 240));
      $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, maxLength));
      $('.alert_textarea').show(); // Simple alert
    }
    else
    {
      $('.alert_textarea').hide();
    }
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input id="inf_notes_1" type="text" size="80" /><br>
<input id="inf_notes_2" type="text" size="80" /><br>
<input id="inf_notes_3" type="text" size="80" /><br>
<input id="inf_notes_4" type="text" size="80" /><br>

<textarea id="inf_notes" style="width: 500px; height: 100px;"></textarea>
</form>
<div class="alert_textarea" style="display:none;">Your text is too long!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's based only on the length and .substring() method,

1. can handle any user input, including "%_%" tricky and breaking string.
2. you must use **keyup** event, instead of keydown or keypress, so the last typed character is not neglected.
3. We shall renew input text with each "keyup" in case the user press the key continuously without releasing it.

Comment: The script does not need "super" validation.. It's for "in-store" usage only.

Thx for the suggestion by the way!